# Scrolling for a gt table chunk in Flexdashboard or Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have the following dashboard:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
````

````
Tab 1
=======================================================================

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
mtcars %>%
  gt()
````

[image]

But I can't see all the table generated by `gt` because I can't scroll it. So I tried to add a css style chunk:

```
.chart-stage {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

But I can achieve what I want, which is to add a scroll bar to see all the table. Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reviewing the css selectors, this is the solution for the question, you'll have to add this chunk to allow scrolling:

````
    ```{css}
    .chart-shim {
      overflow: auto;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: Curiously, this worked for my Flexdashboard in RStudio Viewer, but not in the browser.

Comment: Hello @Mikhail, I tested the solution in Safari and Firefox. What browser do you use?

Comment: It's working now. I suspect I added a comment in the CSS chunk, like I'd do with an R chunk, and that stopped it from working. My bad.

Comment: Any way to accomplish this for just one particular panel/tab in a Flexdashboard dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, tried many things and ultimately found this solution using the htmltools package

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
require(htmltools)
```




Tab 1
=======================================================================

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
div(style='height:800px; overflow-y: scroll', gt(mtcars))
```
````